# pg_restore delimiter

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql

I have a Postgresql dump (created with pg_dump, custom compressed format).  I would like to pg_restore it to STDOUT, but replace the tab separations with pipes.  I've tried just using piping through tr, but I do have a large number of text fields that actually contain tabs, and tr obviously does not respect quotes.  There are tens of billions of output rows (the compressed file is > 500 GB), so I do need a relatively efficient solution.

Comment: It sounds like this dump contains only one table. Correct? Anyway, the easy (but not necessarily fast) way is certainly to restore to a PostgreSQL database, then use `\copy (SELECT format('%s|%s|%s',col1,col2,co3)) TO stout` in `psql`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Craig.  I actually do have multiple tables and regardless I think the solution you propose will take far too long.

Comment: Right now I'm playing around with python csv, but I think it's actually too slow as well.

Answer (score 1):

If it has to be fast, use C. Save

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c, quoted = 0;
    while (c = getchar(), c != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '"') quoted = !quoted;
        if (c == '\t' && !quoted) c = '|';
        putchar(c);
    }
    return quoted;
}
```

e. g. as bartab.c, compile with `gcc bartab.c -o bartab`, and pipe through the resulting program.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use

```
COPY tablename TO STDOUT WITH CSV DELIMITER '|';
```

Do this from inside a db rather than using your dump files.

A second option would be to do new dumps using the --inserts switch and then parse the lines starting with INSERT.  That too would be slow.